# The perfect combination of Maven, Gitflow and Bamboo

Tags: git, maven, version-control, versioning, git-flow

We recently moved to from SVN to Git, and we tried to implement a gitflow development process. But we have problems with using it like it should. Ideally, we would like to have the flow like Nvie has described in his [blogpost](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

While implementing this, we came accross multiple issues.

- The model tells us, that the HEAD revision in the 'master' branch is always the version in production. But when using the maven-release-plugin, it will upgrade the version to SNAPSHOT, crossing out this feature.
- How do we work with the release branches? We could use the [jgitflow](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/Home) plugin, but when we start the release, it will transform the version to a 'released' version, something like 2.3.2. But what if there are issues on that release branch? We cannot fix them, unless we upgrade that version to SNAPSHOT, fix the problem and make another RELEASE.
- Then we use Bamboo, and we have 3 environments, TST, STG and PRD. On the TST version, we deploy the builds from the 'develop' branch, and make releases (not to be confused with maven releases) on every build. But for STG and PRD, we create a new release from the master branch en deploy them on STG, and if it works out correctly, PRD.

I would really want to know how to handle the versioning of a maven project and how to release them (the maven release thing) using Gitflow. Because now we can do one-click release/deploy to STG and PRD from within Bamboo, but also from Jira.

Should we use [jgitflow](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jgit-flow/wiki/Home), and if so, how should we use it? How should we do the versioning? Stuff like that.

I've been looking for this on the internet for a few days now, but I can't seem to find out what people have been doing with this kind of setup. All I can find is, "use Gitflow", "Create maven releases with jgitflow", but I can't seen to find out the combination between all of them.

I hope somebody will explain to me how this **can** work (because I know everybody has it's own implementations and will deviate from others a littlebit) or point out what I am doing wrong.

I appreciate every answer, even if it just points me in the right direction but doesn't give me the solution.

Comment: I posted a similar question on the Atlassian answers, because I did not find a good solution just yet. https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/42665878/answers/42667295 Could somebody please help me with it?

Comment: About issues on the release branch: use `hotfix` or dump that release branch and create another when issues are fixed.